# MATLAB date format

Tags: datetime, matlab

I'm trying to convert date string to date number using dtstr2dtnummx (three time faster than datenum), but for this input

> dtstr2dtnummx({'2010-12-12
>   12:21:13.101'},'yyyy-mm-dd
>   HH:MM:SS.FFF')

and this input

> dtstr2dtnummx({'2010-12-12
>   12:21:13.121'},'yyyy-mm-dd
>   HH:MM:SS.FFF')

getting the same output. I used the following [tutorial](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/bspgcx2-1.html#bsplnu3-4)  to build up the date format.

Ahh sorry, **UPDATED**

Comment: Those look exactly the same to me.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding format of 'FFF' in ***datenum*** is 'SSS' in ***dtstr2dtnummx***, as can be seen in cnv2icudf.m line #126. The end result is:

```
>> d1 = dtstr2dtnummx({'2010-12-12 12:21:13.101'},'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
d1 =
      734484.514734965

>> d2 = dtstr2dtnummx({'2010-12-12 12:21:13.121'},'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS')
d2 =
      734484.514735197

>> % double check the results - difference should equal 0.02 secs:
>> secsPerDay = 24*60*60;
>> timeDiff = secsPerDay * (d2-d1)
timeDiff =
      0.019996
```

I have now posted an article about this on http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/datenum-performance/